# Can we change how UX.SE appears in the chat rooms?

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

The chat rooms "onebox" certain links, which is another example of why StackOverflow is so much fun to use.  If we post a link to the home page of a StackExchange site, it's replaced with the logo of that site.  It works in most cases, but for one (hilariously ironic) site, the results are a bit different:
[image: UX example]

The way the logo blends in with the background can be fixed with a little bit of outlining.

Comment: Even worse it's white-on-white in beta SE chats

Comment: I like the use of "*...which is another example of why StackOverflow is so much fun to use*". Nice way to butter up the admins! ;)